# Different scales on multiple purchased models and mixamo/fuse models

Tags: import

I purchased a classroom scene online (.obj file), and imported it into blender. At first it appeared nothing was there, but apparently it's just insanely small and no where near the default center point/grid. Once I realized this I was able to locate the classroom and work with all the objects in the room as normal. However, now I want to import a character from mixamo and adobe fuse (.fbx file). When I import the .fbx, it works, but it appears at the default center of the grid like most imported objects normally would.. This means the character is MUCH larger than the classroom. It also means that the classroom is extremely far away from my character at the center of the default grid. Is there a way for me to import my character into my classroom directly (where it is currently located), and at a smaller size automatically?...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using rigs and are not the rigger, restrain from scaling them. Some rigs work with absolute values and would not be functional at a different scale.

Scale up and move your static meshes (classroom). This can only be done after importing the .obj file into Blender.